# How to perform Power with large long results in .NET?

Tags: .net, math

Recently was trying to solve a bug in a program, and realised the problem was in the below code (the types weren't bytes, but assume for this question they cannot be larger than that, since certain combinations can result in an overflow):

```
long GetValue(byte x, byte y, byte z) {
  return (long)Math.Pow(x, y) * z;
}
```

Given example values of: x = 27, y = 12, z = 7

Then:

```
a = 27 ^ 12 = 150,094,635,296,999,121
r = a * 7 = 1,050,662,447,078,993,847
```

However, the C#.NET code will give:

```
a = 27 ^ 12 = 150,094,635,296,999,136
r = a * 7 = 1,050,662,447,078,993,952
```

The clue is in the Math.Pow function, which expresses the return as:

```
1.5009463529699914E+17
```

This is because the Math.Pow function only exists for doubles, and doubles have a level of imprecision beyond a certain fractional value.  Since the result is getting close to long.MaxValue, that imprecise floating point maths is affecting the long value resulting from the cast.

There is no equivalent Math.Pow function for longs.  Something tells me the excuse is because under the hood, longs and doubles are 64-bit numbers no matter how you express them.  However (to my mind) longs should not be using floating point maths.

Does this mean that a CPU cannot perform precise calculations with non-fractional values above 32-bit?  That seems highly improbable to me since the Windows Calculator can get this maths right.

How is a problem such as this supposed to be solved within .NET?  I'm sort of assuming that I've missed a function somewhere.

(The original problem I've resolved by changing the approach of the solution design to no longer need this code, but I thought I'd post the question anyway as it was interesting.)

Regards,
Rob.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `BigInteger` class to work with arbitrary precision integers. This is the canonical solution for your problem.

If you do not require numbers bigger than `long.MaxValue` you can write yourself a naive power function as well.

The CPU works with fixed size integers. Arbitrary size integers are a software solution.

Comment: Ah, thanks, was able to re-write the original code so that it now works.  The original solution was written back in 2005 and apparently there was no BigInteger at the time.  Progress :)